# Report showing grand parents with no grandchildrens

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, joined-reports

Can we build a report to  list down all grand parents with no grandchildren's?

For e.g., Lets say we have following data model
Contacts --[lookup]--> JobAllocation ---[MasterDetail]--> JobAllocationSchedules

So need list of all contacts who don't have ANY JobAllocationSchedules ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Create a report type that starts at object JobAllocation with Contacts. Create a new report using this new report type, then do a cross filter set to JobAllocations without JobAllocationSchedules.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Create a RSF field on `JobAllocation` that is the SUM of the count of `JobAllocationSchedules`. Call this new field: `JobAllocationScheduleCount__c`

Then, in the proper report type, you can filter on Contacts with JobAllocationScheduleCount__c = 0